# SMS List of Numbers Subscription Status

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api

Is there currently anyway to do any of the following

.NET Soap or REST either way is fine.

1) Retrieve SMS numbers that have OptIn or status of "Subscribed"
2) Request list filtered by daterange

Having issues figuring this out.

Comment: What people are talk about about? Are these stored in Users, Contacts, Leads or something else?

Comment: SMS Contacts in MobileConnect

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to send SMS, you may want to look into [twillio](https://www.twilio.com/). Not sure, though, as your question is unclear.

Comment: We send SMS through ExactTarget api fine.  I need to retrieve a list of all the contacts who said yes to the double optIn preferably by a date range.  I looked into RetrieveRequest but don't see the ability

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget) API includes the POST /contact/search resource that slows you to find specified contacts based on attributes provided in the JSON parameters.  Go to  http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/searchSchema.html to review these parameters.  Please keep in mind that the API only returns contact IDs and contact keys.  If you would like a list of numbers, I suggest pulling a report from the UI.

You can see message stats in the Marketing Cloud UI.   Just log in at mc.exacttarget.com and go to the MobileConnect application.  From there you will click on the message in the message list.   This will open up the message details screen that gives you stats for the specific douple opt-in.  You can pull a message detail report from this screen by clicking “Create Report.”

Comment: Right now we make a rest call

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/queueMO/history/
Passing identifier and token

We then loop through the results to find if we sent them a text that starts with "You signed up to receive text alerts" 

This is done to see if they approved the "Double Opt-In"

What I want is to make an API call that pulls back ALL numbers that have "subscribed" as their status in a certain time frame.

Something that can make the process of updating our database on who double opt-in much more efficient than querying every phonenumber individually.

Comment: This needs to be an automated process.  NOT a manual report run.  I want to update our SQL database.

Comment: We do not currently offer an automated solution that would solve your need.  As a work around, you could place AMPscript in the initial and final MT of your double opt-in, which would take the mobile number of the device you are sending to and store it in a data extension.  This solution allows you to track how many subscribers started the opt-in vs. how many completed the entire double opt-in.  Keep in mind that it would only work for future opt-ins.